# Can't register CosmosDB binding extension in Azure Functions V2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to add a new function(Http Trigger) with CosmosDB input binding.

Reading a manual about input bindings in Azure Functions Version 2 I see that I need to register my binging extension(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#register-binding-extensions), and azure portal should show me some prompt for registration(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#azure-portal-development)

I'm confused, because I do not see in templates choice for CosmosDB input binding and therefore any of prompts. So I tried to add code manually in function.json like this:

```
{
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "name": "inputDocument",
  "databaseName": "DBName",
  "collectionName": "CollectionName",
  "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnect",
  "direction": "in",
  "Id": "myid",
  "partitionKey": "mypartitionkey"
}
```

And when I trying to switch on my function C# code I see error **"Function error(MyFuncName): The binding type(s) 'cosmosDB' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed."**

On this page I see that CosmosDB input bindings is supported for Azure Functions Version 2(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Azure CosmosDB input/output binding template has been available, don't forget to click `install`.

[image]

---

You met something Azure portal may have planned to support in the future. For now there is no cosmosdb binding option for v2 function, only in v1 it's available. Have opened an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/issues/724) to track this feature support.

The workaround is to Create a Cosmos DB trigger to install cosmosdb extensions(no need to create trigger actually, only use it to get installation prompt), but we still have to code manually in function.json to add bindings.

[image]

Comment: Workaround very cool. But I have some trouble. When I pressed button "Install" the process seems to be started and through two seconds it just interrupted, without any error.

Comment: @AlfredBauer Could you elaborate the `interrupted`? Do you mean the installation panel just disappear without error?

Comment: I see progress ring wich turns around two seconds and then just stopped. Installation panel don't dissapear. Could you try to install this extenstion for yourself?

Comment: @AlfredBauer Yeah, I have done this many times before. Does that panel  show "Extensions not Installed" as before or a "continue" button? The installation could be done in the background, you can go to `https://<funcappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to check. Navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` If you see a `bin` folder with 114 items and a `extensions.csproj`, it means the installation succeeds.

Comment: No, after two seconds button "Install" is becoming to active again. About console and root directory I will give you answer later today.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I had big problem with internet connection.
I've tried to install the extension again and it was successful. Problem is gone.

Comment: @JerryLiu I have been facing the same problem, but in my case, the functions are defined in a Docker container -- while creating the Function App, I choose `OS=Linux`, `Publish = Docker Image`, and point to the relevant docker image from container registry. The function has a `QueueTrigger` with `cosmosDB` binding. Since the app is created with Docker container, I am not getting any option to create `Cosmos DB Trigger` as you suggested. Any ideas on how do we get this working with Docker? Thank you for help!

Comment: @ShirishT I may find your problem, you need to make sure the extension is installed before the image is built. If your work-runtime is dotnet, add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.1" />` in `.csproj` file. If it's node, run `func extensions intall -p Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB -v 3.0.1` under your function app root, where `extensions.csproj` locates.

Comment: Yes @JerryLiu, that indeed fixed the problem. All I needed to do is to install the extension (right version of it) through command line, in my particular case at least. Thank you so much for your reply.