# The binding type(s) 'cosmosDBTrigger' are not registered + Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to get an Azure function to trigger when a new document is added to my CosmosDb.
So I thought I'd implement [this solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---example).

Though, I'm getting the error:

> The binding type(s) 'cosmosDBTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed

**On both local and Azure!**

So, I know that when you create a function from the portal, you've got that `Install` button as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51887247/8126132).
But I'm using Visual Studio so all that is not even showing up on the Azure Portal.

I've checked and I do have the latest `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB` NuGet package. According to documentation, this should be the only thing I need.
Clearly not... All my packages and Visual Studio 2017 are up to date.

I'm using Functions v2 and I do have `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>` in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong NuGet package, if you want to bind cosmosDBTrigger you should use [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#supported-apis). You could know it from the doc:[Packages - Functions 2.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#packages---functions-2x).

Or you could just create the CosmosDB Function with Visual Studio, it will automatically add the package. Or add the package with Nuget manager.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB